# HTML Parser for Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, html-parser

I'm looking for easy to implement module (or a function) for Appcelerator Titanium Mobile that could parse html code (stripping unneeded tags and cleaning up the code) and spitting out just the content.

I know there's an option to use webview in mobile development, but it would add additional overhead, consuming device resources and slowing down your application. so it is not an option.

I also found this post on official appcelerator forum:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/60731/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html
but it is 2 years old and I never managed to get it to work.

Ideally, the solution I'm looking for would adhere to commonjs practices used in Titanium Mobile (and nodejs).

Comment: [html parser](https://gist.github.com/1016047) ThIs link may help you in parsing HTML