# Parsing badly written HTML in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, titanium

I'm trying to get some values out of a small piece of HTML in Titanium.
I tried to use this library: https://gist.github.com/bob-sims/4406293 as answered in another question ([HTML Parser for Titanium Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335431/html-parser-for-titanium-mobile)) but I just can't get anything out of it. The fact that it has no documentation at all and that I'm new to Titanium is probably not helping.

The html comes from this page: http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/objectSearch/cttObjectSearch.jspx?showResults=true&lang=01&pesqObjecto.objectoId=RD057055721PT and I'm trying to get the values under: `<tr id="object_RD057055721PT" class="object">` and `<tr id="details_0" class="detailsDiv detailsHide">` and this is the code I wrote:

```
var select = require('lib/soupselect').select, htmlparser = require('lib/htmlparser');

var handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler(function(err, dom) {
    if (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    } else {
        Ti.API.info("dom" + dom);
        var body = select(dom, 'meta[property="og:object_RD057055721PT"]');
        rows.forEach(function(body) {
            Ti.API.info(body.children[0].data)
        });

        var rows = select(dom, 'div.row');
        Ti.API.info("rows: " + rows)

        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            Ti.API.info(row.children[0].data)
        });
    }
});

function renderXML() {
    var httpResponse = this.responseText;

    var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
    parser.parseComplete(httpResponse);
};

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : renderXML,
    onerror : errorMessage,
})

xhr.open("GET", "http://www.ctt.pt/feapl_2/app/open/objectSearch/cttObjectSearch.jspx?showResults=true&lang=01&pesqObjecto.objectoId=RD057055721PT");
xhr.send();
```

But all the output I get from this is:

> dom[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object]

Comment: Your getting objects back, so try debugging to look at the actual content inside the row. Or alternatively, try this:  `Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(row.children[0].data));` to see what is inside the Object.

Comment: @JosiahHester I tried that, both with `Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(row.children[0].data));` under the ` rows.forEach(function(row) {` and with Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(dom.children[0].data)); under the mail `else` loop, but nothing came out.

Comment: Why dont you set a breakpoint at those lines and see whats going on by using the debugger.

Comment: @JosiahHester I did. The thing is, the dom object is indeed with all the page scattered in lots of data structures inside it, but the queries I do, like the one you suggested or the one I put in the code of the original question, are all empty. Like I said, I think this is a problem of me not knowing exactly how to get the data I want not of the parser. But since the parser doesn't come with any documentation at all, I'm in the dark.

Comment: As an alternative, you could load these into a Webview component, then insert jQuery, and use it to fetch the DOM components.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) it will parse unknown HTML much better and gives back nice JSON response.

Comment: Yes, but some sites are blocking yql services, for example those that do not allow robot indexing.